# Can't run two for loop statement within same if statement?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have the following JS code, I feel weird that only the first for loop can run, but the 2nd part doesn't work. I even tried to make two different if statement and include the for loop separately, but the same thing happened. If I run the for loop separately (by deleting another for loop), both of them can run, means both of the logic should be correct. Please help.

```
var s = "<?php printf($resultDataOrderInfo[0][status]); ?>";

   if(s == "Processing"){
       var t = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
       for (i=0; i<=t.length; i++){
           t[i].setAttribute("readonly","true");
       }  // only this above part can run

       var d = document.getElementsByName("delete");
       for (i=0; i<=d.length; i++){
           d[i].setAttribute("hidden","true");
       }
   }
```

Comment: There's no reason they shouldn't be both be able to run. Can you reproduce this issue in a jsFiddle ?

Comment: "doesn't work" is bad explanation - please use debugger and step through the code to provide good details in the post. (F12 will bring dev tools in most desktop browsers)

Comment: Are you sure d.length != 0 ?

Comment: @stackErr - why using new variable matters? it is global variable anyway, should not really matter if used in one or both loops as it is initialized to 0 anyway in both cases.

Comment: @stackErr that doesnt make a difference since i is set to 0 in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for everybody answering. Ok, I've tried to change variable name from i to g for the second loop, same thing happened. Then I set it like local by var i or g=0;, same thing. @mortsahl Yes, I'm sure d.length!=0, because when I delete the t part, the d part can run, so I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Don't use global variables -- it is very bad practice and along the same lines as using eval ... just say no

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov since it is global, the variable could be changed by an asynchronous call such as setTimeout/setInterval/AJAX. It is better practice to keep it local and seperate indexor for two different loops. Anyways deleted the comment since OP tried it and it didn't work

Comment: My fault, by Christopher Thomas Nicodemus' hint, after changing <= to <, both of the loop work. Thank you everybody.

Comment: @stackErr: It can't be changed by async code. Async code is unable to break into the current synchronous execution of code. Even if it's timed such that it would have landed at that exact time, it has to wait. If that wasn't the case, then using a separate variable name wouldn't help since the async code could break in during the loop as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to change all of the <= to <.  If length is equal to 0, then it is going to execute once, but fail due to the length being zero.  Which, I believe is the issue of it not reaching the second for loop, due to an error occurring on the first.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it matters whether or not `t.length` is 0.

Comment: Thank you Christopher. By changing all <= to <, both of of the loop work. Since I know both t.length and d.length are not 0, but I think the script paused on error because if I write i<=t.length, when i=t.length, the script can't actually find the t[i] tag, because it doesn't exist, then the script hangs.